# Insert React "root" dom to be programatically on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-dom

Let’s say there is a  somewhere in my HTML file:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

To render a React element into that DOM node, I pass it in to ReactDOM.render():

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But what if that node is created programmatically, after say a user logs in so there is a delay in rendering it. To illustrate, I'm trying to do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="root" data-user="1"></div>'
        }, 3000)
    </script>
```

This doesn't work. ReactDOM doesn't find anything on the first pass when it looks for `document.getElementById('root')` and so it renders nothing. Is there a way to do it dynamically?

Comment: Have you considered loading the JS files after the DOM is rendered? Adding the JS at the end of the page?

Comment: *To illustrate, I'm trying to do something like* - this should be done inside React application, so you would have full control over precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body id="body">
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
 <script type="text/babel">
  document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = `
       <div id="app"></div>
  `; 

  const name = 'Josh Perez'; 
  const element = <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>; 
  ReactDOM.render( element, document.getElementById('app') );
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```